# Qual a diferença de SCRIPT_FILENAME e REQUEST_FILENAME?

Tags: apache, htaccess

Estou estudando URL amigável, e em muitos exemplos me deparei com estas duas formas de escrita:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

e

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
```

Qual a diferença entre elas? Olhando a documentação do Apache eu entendi que são a mesma coisa. Será que entendi certo?

Comment: O valor é o mesmo, em princípio. REQUEST_FILENAME é pra fazer par como REQUEST_URI, nunca vi nada falando de algum caso que não fosse o mesmo valor. Em teoria, apontam pra mesma estrutura interna do Apache. Não faço idéia da razão de ter as duas. Teria que olhar documentação antiga pra ver se antes era só SCRIPT_FILENAME, aí faria sentido um "apelido" novo depois, pra combinar com o REQUEST_URI, como comentei. De qq forma, é uma dúvida legítima.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @Bacco :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SCRIPT_FILENAME** :
É o nome da variável CGI geralmente conhecido

**REQUEST_FILENAME** : É a contrapartida apropriada de REQUEST_URI (que contém o valor do campo uri de request_rec).

Ambas contêm o mesmo valor.